# Install4j - combo box component configuration conditions

Tags: java, install4j

We are using Installer 6.1.6.
Today we support SQL server authentication and I wish to add a new ability of *Windows authentication mode*.

Our database configuration is set as *configuration form* and I want to add a new combo-box form component which will include the 2 server authentications options.

1. Is it possible to define the combo-box's *Windows Authentication* option with a *condition expression* for Windows OS only? (it doesn't make sense to display it for Linux users)
2. Some of the form components are *"username"* & *"password"*. In case the user chooses the *windows authentication mode* these fields aren't relevant anymore. Is it possible to conceal them in that case?
3. Is the combo-box option could lead to a conflict when running the installer with a quite mode? Is it set the 1st option as a default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to define the combo-box's Windows Authentication option
>   with a condition expression for Windows OS only? (it doesn't make
>   sense to display it for Linux users)

You can set the "Drop-down list entries" property of the "Drop-down list" form component to an installer variable that contains a string array:

```
${installer:authenticationOptions}
```

In the pre-activation script of the form, you can set the variable with code like:

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add("One");
options.add("Two");
if (Util.isWindows()) {
    options.add("Three");
}
context.setVariable("authenticationOptions", options.toArray(new String[0]));
```

> Some of the form components are "username" & "password". In case the
>   user chooses the windows authentication mode these fields aren't
>   relevant anymore. Is it possible to conceal them in that case?

Yes, by disabling the components in the "Selection change script" property with code like this:

```
// to disable
formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("123").setEnabled(!selectedItem.equals("Windows authentication"));
// or to hide
formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("123").setVisible(!selectedItem.equals("Windows authentication"));
```

> Is the combo-box option could lead to a conflict when running the installer 
>   with a quite mode?

By default, the first index is selected. This is configurable with the "Initially selected index" property of the "Drop-down list" form component.

**Alternative solution:**

I would consider using "Single radio button" form components for your authentication options. They are all bound to the same variable name in order to form a group and have the same effect as a drop-down list. With the "Visibility script" property you can hide some options depending on the OS, for example with

```
Util.isWindows()
```

and option is only visible on Windows. With the "Coupled form components" tab in the configuration area, you can select other form components that are disabled or enabled depending on the selection.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.
For the 2nd point of your answer - if I just set the "Visibility script" with _Util.isWindows()_, it means that in windows they will always be presented. When the user chooses _windows authentication_ option these field should be grayed out or alternatively get hidden.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please see my edit, also the "Alternative solutions" at the bottom

Comment: I've set the installer variable ${installer:authenticationOptions} as the Combo box entries property (it was more convenient to me than the drop-list) with the pre-activation script you suggested and it's works great. My problem occurs when I run the installer with "Quite Mode". I always get the following error: com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:authenticationOptions. Isn't the first index should be selected by default? Am I must set the `authenticationOptions` as an empty "Pre defined installed variable" and pass it's value though the command line?

Comment: In unattended mode, the pre-activation script is not executed. So yes, adding the variable as a pre-defined installer variable is needed in that case.